# why does my phonegap app restart if kept in background for long

Tags: ios, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap-cli

my phonegap app restarts if kept in background for long. For example if i open my app the next day it relaunches rather than starting from where i left off. Otherwise it seems to preserve state perfectly.

I see this happening for some other apps too that are installed on the iphone like instagram, twitter, but not for facebook and whatsapp. Does iOS kill apps if in background for long? Can i prevent this?

I am using Phonegap CLI 6.0.1 (cordova build version 4.0.1) testing on iOS9. Let me know if any other information is needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS will kill apps when it needs the resources. There is nothing you can do to prevent your app from being killed (by iOS or the user). This has nothing to do with your app being made with phonegap (or anything else).

You need to code your app to handle being killed. When the user chooses to use your app again (after it happened to be killed), your app should launch right back to where it was, restoring its previous state. This is what all good apps do.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Just for info - are hybrid apps more prone to getting killed to free up resources? Are native apps better in this aspect?

Comment: It makes no difference. It's just about resources. If iOS needs more resources and a suspended app is taking up too many resources - it gets killed.

Comment: Thanks for the same!